# how to specify an accuracy level while google maps geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am using google geocoder api

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=dach&sensor=false`

**How can i set the accuracy for the gmap geocoding api** to i.e. "only countries and cities"?

As an example, searching for "dach" currently i get the results:

- Dalandstraße, 81927 Munic, Germany
- Dacha, Kirovohradsaoblast, Ukraine
- DA Lane, Deep Run, NC, 28525, USA

(which includes street names and stuff)

What i really want: (set a filter for only countries, places and cities)

- Dachau, Germany
- Dachstein, Austria

How can i set the geo filter **to only return cities and countries?**

Comment: There is no option to set such a filter, you'll need to parse the response on your own to filter the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [call the API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=dach&sensor=false), you can see, for each result, a `type` array, for example :

> "types" : [ "route" ]

So, you will have to create your own filter to determine wich result(s) you're interesting in, depending of this `types` parameter.

You can find all the possible values of `type` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) .